# MySQL Update a Complete Column data from Another Table with same Primary Key (30 Million Row)

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, large-data

I have two tables: Final and Primary in my MySQL database.
Final Table:

```
UID (Primary Key), Surface (Varchar), BCD_Value (Int , Index), Env_Value (Int)
```

Primary Table:

```
UID (Primary Key), BCD_Value (Int , Index)
```

There are 30 Million rows in each table. Primary Table has the correct BCD_Value. I have to update Final Table's BCD_Value with values from Primary on matching UID.

I was using following in MySQL command line

```
update Primary pri, Final fin set fn.BCD_Value = pri.BCD_Value where fin.UID = pri.UID
```

But it does nothing after 36 hours.

Further, I have implemented a code in perl which creates update statement for 5000 rows at time (loops it for 30 million/ 5000 times). Now it is working but I desperately need to fasten it.

Answer (score 1):

try converting into `ANSI SQL-92` syntax

```
UPDATE Final fin INNER JOIN `Primary` pri
       ON fin.UID = pri.UID
SET fn.BCD_Value = pri.BCD_Value
```

it takes time to update all records because it updates the indexes as well.

try removing the index on `Final.BCD_Value` first then add again after the update has been made.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have implemented your code, but the time remains almost same.

Comment: do you still have index on the column `Final.BCD_Value`?

Comment: Yup. I have to keep that because I'll search the table by that.

Comment: no, i mean just for now. it will recreate the index every CRUD you made because the column has index defined.

Comment: do a EXPLAIN SELECT to know if the query will fatest as posible, then type `show processlist` to know what happen during UPDATE.

Comment: Yeah. Should I drop the Index on that field now? After completion I have to recreate Index again - that'll take another large time. But I am confused - which'll be better.

Comment: question: is the updating of records always? or just for now?

Comment: Just for now. But i have deadline to do it.